# preg_match a specific content

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm really noob about regular expressions and I need a help. I tried lots of things but couldn't get the thing I need.

```
<img src="http://img03.imgsinemalar.com/images/afis_buyuk/m/Maske.jpg" title="Maske (1994) afişi" alt="Maske (1994) afişi" itemprop="image" width="164" height="234"/>
```

At this code *src*, *title*, *alt*, *width* and *height* can have various values. However, *itemprop* is a constant and there is one image at the source with this attribute. How can I get it with PHP?

If my topic is duplicate I'm sorry but I really couldn't find a solution.

Comment: But itemprop ise constant and there is one image at the source with this attribute. ? what does this mean nd what means source here?

Comment: I mean one image has an "itemprop" attribute. And you can check the source from here: view-source:http://www.sinemalar.com/film/1000/maske

Comment: Your source contain lot of img tags with one who have this itemprop attribute? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right.

Comment: why won't go for jquery? because regex for this is seriously much timetaking

Comment: I'm trying to write a bot, it will work by cronjob. Bye the way I can't use it :( I'd know it :) It is really hard. Trying to find a solution for couple hours. At least asked here :)

Comment: What do you want to get by regex?..a..a.attributes?

Comment: I can do it with lots of explode functions but I worried how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
%<img\s+src="(.*?)"\s+title="(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"\s+itemprop="(.*?)"\s+width="(.*?)"\s+height="(.*?)"\s*?/>%
```

---

Example:

```
<?php

$myImage = '<img src="http://img03.imgsinemalar.com/images/afis_buyuk/m/Maske.jpg" title="Maske (1994) afişi" alt="Maske (1994) afişi" itemprop="image" width="164" height="234"/>';

preg_match_all('%<img\s+src="(.*?)"\s+title="(.*?)"\s+alt="(.*?)"\s+itemprop="(.*?)"\s+width="(.*?)"\s+height="(.*?)"\s*?/>%sim', $myImage, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$src= $matches[1][0];
$title= $matches[2][0];
$alt= $matches[3][0];
$itemprop= $matches[4][0];
$width= $matches[5][0];
$height= $matches[6][0];


echo $src."\n";
echo $title."\n";
echo $alt."\n";
echo $itemprop."\n";
echo $width."\n";
echo $height."\n";
```

---

Output:

```
http://img03.imgsinemalar.com/images/afis_buyuk/m/Maske.jpg
Maske (1994) afişi
Maske (1994) afişi
image
164
234
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/tENd2b

---

## update based on your comments:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.sinemalar.com/film/1000/maske");

preg_match_all('%<img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" width="(.*?)" height="(.*?)" />%i', $html, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$src= $matches[1][0];
$alt= $matches[2][0];
$width= $matches[3][0];
$height= $matches[4][0];


echo $src."\n";
echo $alt."\n";
echo $width."\n";
echo $height."\n";
```

---

Output:

```
http://simg02.imgsinemalar.com/img/sinemalarlogo.png
Sinemalar.com
211
51
```

---

Note:

You should use php [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse html not a regex.

Comment: There is a little problem. Preg should match from this links source-code: http://www.sinemalar.com/film/1000/maske . It is started to catch from logo image.

Comment: Now I was reading about php DOMDocument and it is exactly does what I need. Thank you Pedro Lobito.

Comment: I used a PHP classes written by S.C. Chen (simplehtmldom) and use this code worked great for me: 
$html = str_get_html($cek); print_r($html->find('img[itemprop]')[0]->attr['src']);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the whole `<img>` node, you can use DOM with XPath:

```
<?php
   $dom = new DOMDocument;
   $dom->loadHTMLFile("http://www.sinemalar.com/film/1000/maske");
   $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
   $qry = "//img[@itemprop='image']";
   $result = $xp->query($qry)->item(0);
   // To print it
   $newdoc = new DOMDocument();
   $cloned = $result->cloneNode(TRUE);
   $newdoc->appendChild($newdoc->importNode($cloned,TRUE));
   echo $newdoc->saveHTML();
?>
```

It will print (together with some warnings):

```
<img src="http://img03.imgsinemalar.com/images/afis_buyuk/m/Maske.jpg" title="Maske (1994) afi&#351;i" alt="Maske (1994) afi&#351;i" itemprop="image" width="164" height="234">
```

[Demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOEUyYXRTZlhsV3c)